# Merging PPT files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, interop, powerpoint

I have a tricky requirement to be able to merge PPT files on-the-fly in ASP.NET.

I'd like to avoid interop as I know it's not a good idea from ASP.NET.

I came across Aspose.Slides which looks like it would do the job - quite pricey though.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx

Cheaper / simpler suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure someone may have one, but the Aspose products are nice and typically worth it from my experience. I understand everyone has a budget as well though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that you'll only need to work with the newer XML format files (PPTX/PPSX/etc), you may be able to do what you need to by working with the file contents directly.  They're actually zips that contain XML and other related resource files.  Possibly relevant example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850834.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Morgan,

I suggest you to please consider using cloud based version of Aspose.Slides for .NET SDK API in pay as you go mode. This will allow performing some number of operations completely free including merging presentations. I suggest you to please visit [Aspose.Slides for Cloud pricing](https://purchase.aspose.cloud/pricing) options for your convenience.